# DF with values for Time Intervals

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to make a manual dataframe.. I would like to have a time stamp with a time interval, for example:

df1:

| Time Interval | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 10:00 - 11:00 | $15 |
| 11:00 - 12:00 | $10 |
| 15:00 - 16:00 | $18 |

So when I do a left join with df2:

| Van | Route | Departure Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 223 | NY-RO | 10:35 |
| 655 | LA-SD | 15:15 |
| 987 | LA-SF | 15:50 |
| 278 | LA-SD | 11:45 |

The result will be:

| Van | Route | Departure Time | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 223 | NY-RO | 10:35 | $15 |
| 655 | LA-SD | 15:15 | $18 |
| 987 | LA-SF | 15:50 | $18 |
| 278 | LA-SD | 11:45 | $10 |

Comment: why is the price in the last row $10? Shouldn't it be $15?

Comment: I changed it so every price was used and forgot to change it in the first table! sorry. I edited it already.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) on the `Departure Time`s. Note that it expects the columns to be merged on to be sorted, so we sort by time first.

```
df1['Departure Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Time Interval'].str.split(' - ').str[0])
df2['Departure Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Departure Time'])
out = (pd.merge_asof(df2.sort_values(by='Departure Time'), 
                     df1.sort_values(by='Departure Time'), on='Departure Time')
       .drop(columns=['Time Interval']))
out['Departure Time'] = out['Departure Time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M')
```

Output:

```
   Van  Route Departure Time Price
0  223  NY-RO          10:35   $15
1  278  LA-SD          11:45   $10
2  655  LA-SD          15:15   $18
3  987  LA-SF          15:50   $18
```